# $\gcd(2k_1,2k_2−1)=\gcd(k_1,2k_2−1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Prove $\gcd(2k_1,2k_2−1)=\gcd(k_1,2k_2−1)$

Both $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive integers.

I tried to start from the fact that: $\gcd(2,2k-1) = 1$ because they are relatively prime.
But I am not sure how to expand my idea

Comment: Can you show $\gcd(2k_1,2k_2-1)|\gcd(k_1,2k_2-1)$ and $gcd(k_1,2k_2-1)|\gcd(2k_1,2k_2-1)$

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a  divisor of $2k_1$ and $2k_2-1$, $p$ is odd since $2k_2-1$ is odd, this implies $p$ divides $k_1$

Comment: You mean a common divisor or a prime one.

Comment: but why is p a prime

Comment: If $p$ is not prime, the same argument works.

Comment: Im sorry but I still dont get it. Could you explain it with more details plz?

Comment: if the pair $(2k_1,2k_2-1)$ and $(k_1,2k_2-1)$ have the same divisors, they have the same $gcd$.